# How do you do a rowspan in bulma grids?

Tags: html-table, bulma

I want to use Bulma grids to create three boxes with two columns, the left column has two boxes in it, the right column has one box in it. But I want the box in the right column to span both rows of boxes in the left column. To do this in html tables it would look like this:

```
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td rowspan="2">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

The closest I have gotten with bulma is this, but the right most box does not span both rows:

```
<div class="container px-3">
    <div class="columns is-flex is-flex-wrap-wrap">
      <div class="column is-half">
        <div class="box pr-3">
          1
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column is-half">
        <div class="box pl-3" style="height: 100%;">
          2
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column is-half">
        <div class="box">
          3
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```